# Need to extract multiple dates that may have write in one cell

Tags: google-sheets-formula, data-extraction

| A5 | B5 |
| --- | --- |
| This cell contains 01/02/2023, but has 31/01/2023 and 25/12/2022 too | =REGEXEXTRACT(A6;"[0-9]+[0-9]+[/][0-9]+[0-9]+[/][0-9]+[0-9]") |
|  |  |

| A5 | B5 | C5 | D5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| This cell contains 01/02/2023, but has 31/01/2023 and 25/12/2022 too | 01/02/2023 | 31/01/2023 | 25/12/2022 |
|  |  |  |  |

Answer (score 0):

can you try:

```
=INDEX(IFNA(--REGEXEXTRACT(TO_TEXT(SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(B5;"(\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4})";"$1");""));"(\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4})")))
```

- 

[image]

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(A6; REGEXREPLACE(A6; "( \d+/\d+/\d{4})"; "($1)"))
```

[image]

arrayformula:

```
 =INDEX(REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A; REGEXREPLACE(A2:A; "( \d+/\d+/\d{4})"; "($1)")))
```

[image]